# Program needs to read file everytime it changes

Tags: c#

I have a program that reads an XML file (for now, on local computer.) and loads the data into a list of struct.

How can I make it such that if I execute it, it does the above but then waits to keep checking for any change to the file. Should the file be changed, it reads the file all over again.

Do I need to create a file watcher service as described here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/C__FileWatcher.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect File Read in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621661/detect-file-read-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) - the docs give examples.

Basically you create an instance, give it a filter (which would be your exact file in this case), hook up an event handler (probably the `Changed` event in your case) and then set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` class.  You can have it raise an event in your code when the file is changed.

Details can be found on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. You can point it at your XML file and when it changes, it will fire an event so you can then read the file again

Comment: @Robaticus: Totally! I dont know how he gets in so quickly, think he must have cultivated an army to answer all these questions for him...